# nth-child(2) active on nth-child(1) = why?

Tags: css

Here (http://livespot.pl/gw2/forum/) on that black background I need background-size: auto;... but on that white/red background I need background-size: cover;. I can't get that. Why?

```
.l-submain:nth-child(2) {
    background-image: url(http://livespot.pl/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/background.jpeg);
    background-size: auto;
}
```

Comment: You cannot use `nth'` on **classes** unless all siblings have the same class. Please give us a brief rundown of the HTML & CSS  instead of just a link.

Comment: try `.l-main:nth-child(2)` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `:nth-child()` selector selects the *nth* child element regardless of what class it has. In your case, `:nth-child(2)` is the first element with the class `.l-submain`:

[image: Example]

To select the 2nd element with the `.l-submain` class, you'd have to select the third child of `l-main`:

```css
.l-main :nth-child(3) {
    ...
}
```

Or, as it's the last child of `.l-main`:

```css
.l-main :last-child {
    ...
}
```